# Oracle Error ORA-06512 when Copied a Class

Tags: apex, error, oracle

I got this Error When I copied a Old  class And Pasted in the new Controller ..the Reason I did It because It Had a Single Email service Method I wanted to use same Method

Till I Change The New Class Name And Constructor I was Getting This Error
Any Idea about the Error [image]

Comment: You have been caught by one of the seven code processor lives in Slaesforce backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a backend error. SalesForce use Oracle databases and it looks like something went wrong on their end. The "Unique Constraint" error would suggest that the class name already exists in the database, but those errors should never be present to the end user.

If you can reproduce the issue you should report it to SalesForce.

Comment: It's a second time I am getting the error..long back when i was doing the same Step I had got this error

Comment: @user40138 you can loge a support case to salesforce about this, it shows there's a "bug" somewhere they will want to know about.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke  I will raise A Case Tomorrow